Spectroscopy notation: What is $^5D_0$ in Eu$^{3+}$?
I am studying trivalent Europium in spectroscopy and encountered that I have no idea about the spectroscopic notation used in literature. I have a general understanding naming the orbitals (this is probably more atomic spectroscopy) but it seems like in rare earths, this is more complicated. Everyone talks about a transition from $^5D_0$ to $^7F_J$. It is clear to me, that $^7F_J$ is the lower state with the $4f^6$ shell filled according to Hund's rules. But how does $^5D_0$ actually look like? Are the electrons still in $4f^6$?
I feel like I lack some general understanding how this notation works and can't find any good resources on that. I appreciate some good recommendations on literature that explains how this notation works but also an answer to the special $^5D_0$ state in Eu$^{3+}$.
